# Pie Chart: how to display text just on some pie slices using AChartEngine Android library?

Tags: android, charts, achartengine, pie-chart

I'm using **AChartEngine** (http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) library to display a pie chart in an Android app.

The pie chart can have lots of slides. I want to display just on some pie slices the values, but I could not make it work (I'm not even sure it is possible).

For the `DefaultRenderer` I've made:

```
renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);  // color of the text displayed on the chart
renderer.setLabelsTextSize(12); // size of the text displayed on the chart
```

and for each `SimpleSeriesRenderer`:

```
if (pieSlidesNo > 5) {
    serieRender.setDisplayChartValues(false);
} else {
    serieRender.setDisplayChartValues(true);
}
```

but is not working - the values are displayed on each pie slice.
What I want is like in the below image (the values are displayed only on first slices, not on all).

[image]

Comment: I am sorry. Could you tell me please how did you set the "%" on the pie chart slices??? I am using the achartengine library too and I am trying to find out how to do that... Thanks!

Comment: hi user3019105, the image above is not rendered using the lib, is from the internet. I guess without modifying the lib you cannot make what you want because `series` accepts a double value as parameter and you cannot pass there also the `%` sign.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way even to set a border color to the pie chart using the series?

Comment: As far as I know, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have to change Library Source.

Make change in `draw()`  of `PieChart.java`  and use `renderer.setDisplayValues(true);` of `DefaultRenderer`

```
 if (mRenderer.isDisplayValues()) {
        if(angle<60)
        {}
        else
        drawLabel(
            canvas,
            getLabel(mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).getChartValuesFormat(), mDataset.getValue(i)),
            mRenderer, prevLabelsBounds, mCenterX, mCenterY, shortRadius / 2, longRadius / 2,
            currentAngle, angle, left, right, mRenderer.getLabelsColor(), paint, false, true);
      }
```

you can change angle comparison value `(angle<60)` according to ur requirement.

Comment: I'll try that soon. The idea is that I'm using right now the jar file and in this case I will need to take the source code and recompile it. I'll let you know if it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I've added 2 `boolean` variables inside `SimpleSeriesRenderer` bean class: `displayValueOnSlice` (boolean value indicating if we need to display value ON the pie slice) and `displayValueBesideSlice` (boolean value indicating if we need to display value BESIDE the pie slice) and on `PieChart.java` I've changed to display info based on these values. From my app, based on different criterias I decide if I set those 2 values on `true` or `false`. Thanks for your ideea, was very helpfull, so I'm going to accept your answer.